# Android app for photo mass geotagging

Tags: android, photography, geo-location

I'm looking for an Android app (must work on Android 10) which supports mass geotagging of photos. I have a GPX file with the GPS log data and a folder on my SD card with the photos imported from my system camera. The app should geotag the photos based on the location in the GPS based on the time stamp. For a desktop PC, "PhotoMechanic" or "RoboGEO" are doing this job, but I need an Android-only solution. Freeware preferred.